# specific events on resize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a navigation with a logo in it (desktop). On mobile devices the logo is in the header of the page and the navigation a dropdown without the logo.

It put the logo with jQuery out of the navi into the header.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    if (ww < 1180) {
        $("#logo a").appendTo("#header-top").addClass("logo");
        $("#logo").remove();
    } if (bildschirmbreite > 1179) {
        $("#navigation-main .team").after('<li id="logo"></li>');
    }
});
```

Thats no problem and everything is clear. But I still have a few problems if the window is resized e.g. on desktop devices.

Is there a possibility to check if the event appeared, so that it will just appear, when the window sized down and up again? Right now a new list item and the logo, etc. will create again and again, just if the window is resized.

What do I have to do to prevent this?

Regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is usually better achieved with media queries in the CSS.

Styles outside the media query are applied by default- in this case for the desktop site.

```
#logo{
  display: none;
}

#navigation-main .team #logo {
  display: block;
}

/* Styles inside are only applied when the query becomes true, 
in this case when on mobile */

@media (max-width: 1179px) {
    #logo {
        display: block;
    }
    #navigation-main .team #logo {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

You'll get the same result, but you won't need any JavaScript. You'll likely have to tweak your HTML to get the result you want. Read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: But for that I need the logo in the navigation and a second one for the mobile view. That'ts not the thing I wanted, because i've duplicated links, etc.

Comment: Should be fine with one. Put the logo in navigation with 'position: relative' , then in the mobile media query position it with 'fixed' or 'absolute'.